# Kinetic energy of an expanding sphere

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, astrophysics

In the study of Newtonian stellar structure, Weinberg (1972) writes

> The uniform  dilation of a sphere with uniform density will give it a kinetic energy
>   $$U=\frac{3}{10}M\dot R^2$$

I don't know how to derive this, or even really where to begin. Does one resolve the sphere into particles or somehow treat it as a continuum? I'm quite stumped and several online searches have not been fruitful.

So, how does one derive this?

Thanks.

Comment: Isn't $U$ usually used for potential energy?

Comment: @HDE226868: Yes, it is. That *is* strange (I copied directly from the text).

Comment: Weinberg's notation never conforms to what other people use. As for the question, that is surprisingly non-obvious. What is the *definition* of kinetic energy used here? (Given that we have a continuous mass density, $\frac{1}{2}mv^2$ does really seem adequate.)

Comment: @ACuriousMind: I was curious about the *definition* too. I thought is was obvious and I was just missing it. In fact, my Googling has revealed *nothing* useful. Very strange. Would context be helpful?

Comment: Wait, is the *sphere* a *ball* (as implied by Mark below)? (For me, "sphere" means only the boundary of a solid ball)

Comment: I've had this question for quite a long time so I don't recall the context 100%, but considering it's used in the study of an expanding polytrope, it's probably a *ball*.

Comment: @ACuriousMind If I remember correctly, the convention in Newtonian mechanics is to call your "ball" a "sphere" and your "sphere" a "shell"; at least, that's why it's called the [shell theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_theorem).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just imagine an expanding shell. Then all the parts are moving at the same speed. If the mass is $M$ and the radius is $R$, then the kinetic energy is $\frac{1}{2} M \dot{R}^2$.

A sphere is just a series of shells. A shell at radius $r$ has mass $\mathrm{d}m = \frac{M}{4/3 \pi R^3} 4\pi r^2 \mathrm{d}r$ and is expanding at a rate proportional to the expansion rate of the sphere times the shell's fractional distance from the center. Thus we can integrate

$$U = \int_0^R \frac{1}{2} (\frac{r}{R} \dot{R})^2 \frac{M}{4/3 \pi R^3} 4\pi r^2 \mathrm{d}r$$

Evaluating obtains the expression in the question.

Comment: Why $(r\dot R/R)^2$?

Comment: It says that if, for example, the sphere is expanding at 2cm/s on the outside and you look at a point half way from the center to the outside, that point is expanding at 1 cm/s.